# This iPhone 7 Plus (Model 1661, 1784, 1785, 1786) is running iOS 13.5.1 (17F80), which may not be supported by this version of Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

i get this error message when trying to build and run my app on personal device. Anyone know a fix? I need the phone to properly QA the app.

*This iPhone 7 Plus (Model 1661, 1784, 1785, 1786) is running iOS 13.5.1 (17F80), which may not be supported by this version of Xcode. An updated version of Xcode may be found on the App Store or at developer.apple.com.*

MAC Version 10.15.5
Phone Version: 13.5.1
Xcode Version: 11.3.1

Comment: here is a device support file you can download it and add it https://github.com/filsv/iPhoneOSDeviceSupport

Comment: @RuchiMakadia sry, I've never had to do this before. So, i should download iOS 13.6?

Comment: you can download both 13.5 and 13.6 and add it
if your ios version is 13.5.1 so you can download 13.5 then also work

Comment: "Xcode Version: 11.3.1" That's the culprit. Nowadays, it's more or less the two minor/patch of Xcode matches the iOS version compatible one.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to upgrade Xcode to v11.5